# Drupal 6: Hook for altering help field in a form

Tags: forms, drupal-6, hook

I have a form, and want to programmatically alter the help text that displays at the top of the page. Is there a hook available to do this?

**EDIT**: by "help text", I mean the text entered into the CCK form at: admin/content/node-type/sample-form

Above the textbox, it is labeled:

> Explanation or submission guidelines:

The textarea has the id `edit-help`

Below, there is the text:

> This text will be displayed at the top
>   of the submission form for this
>   content type. It is useful for helping
>   or instructing your users.

Is this specific enough?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by the 'help text'. Is it text from the form itself (always shown) or do you mean the messages that might show after form submission (e.g. validation error messages, etc.)?

Comment: Yes, specific enough - see answer below ;)

Comment: Hmm - looks like it was not specific enough *for me* - sorry for not reading your clarification thoroughly. I rewrote my answer below to (hopefully ;) match your question now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The help texts are returned by the modules [`hook_help()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_help/6) implementations, so for *adding* your own, this would be the place to look.

As for *altering* a help text that gets set by a different modules [`hook_help()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_help/6), this is a bit more tricky. Take a look at [`theme_help()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/theme_help/6) - this is where the help text gets assembled, via a call to [`menu_get_active_help()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/menu_get_active_help/6), which in turn invokes the modules [`hook_help()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_help/6) implementations.

So your **first option** for this seems to be an override of [`theme_help()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/theme_help/6), either by omitting the call to [`menu_get_active_help()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/menu_get_active_help/6) and setting your own value directly, or you make the call and modify the result before returning it.

It will be a bit difficult to determine your context in that override, as the [`theme_help()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/theme_help/6) function gets called for every page rendered and does not offer any parameters from which you could get the information if you are on the right page (the form page you want to alter). You'd probably have to use the [arg()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/arg/6) function for this, if the forms page has a distinctly recognizable path structure.

A **second option** to get at the help text would be one step later, by altering the content of the $help variable passed to page.tpl.php. You could implement your own `preprocess_page(&$variables)` function and alter the content of `$variables['help']` there. You'd still need to find out if you are on the right page, but the $variables array contains a lot of information that could help you there.

Comment: I tried doing this, but I couldn't find the value to unset. (I did a print_r and looked through the whole thing.) It's not the help text for a specific field, but for the entire form.

Comment: Yup, I missunderstood your question completely in my first try, so that could not work. Rewrote answer completely to match your question now (hopefully ;)

Comment: Is there a way I could do the second option without tying myself to the theme I edit? I'd like to have separate files, so if I switch themes I'll still have my modifications.

Comment: As for not tying yourself to the theme, you can implement preprocess functions in modules also. That way they will be called regardless of the active theme, as long as the module is enabled.

Comment: FWIW, the first option worked fine for me (a MY_THEME_help() in my template.php). I checked the URL with this condition: if (arg(0)."/".arg(1)."/".arg(2)=="admin/content/node" && !arg(3))